# HTTPS authentication over WiFi using HttpClient 4

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, httpclient

I have Android pet-project DroidIn which utilizes HttpClient 4 (built into Android) to do some form based authentication. I started noticing that people who are using WiFi are reporting connection problems. It also doesn't help that site I'm accessing has self-assigned certificate. Well - the question is (I'm quite vague on WiFi details) If WiFi at the hotspot doesn't support HTTPS would that be a good enough reason for connection to fail and is there anything that I can do beside proxying into another appserver using HTTP which then would call HTTPS site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wifi is just a low level protocol, you are dealing with HTTP & TCP/IP which is unaware of wifi.
So you can ignore the fact that you are using wifi, just try to see if the server is accessible from the client side. (try a telnet on the https port which is 443 by default)

Comment: I understand. But here's the catch: site is accessible from same device G1) when using web browser and app works just fine from the emulator that uses direct LAN at the same location.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem in my Air app. It's called Postal, a mail tracking app for Brazilian service. (I'd appreciate if you try it in wifi and feed me back).
It always works on 2G/3G but rarely works when connected to  wi-fi. Everything else works but AIR APPS! Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt in the same phone and/or access point. And when it's not working, any other AIR app is not working also.

Even the Tour de Flex Mobile AMF Remoting test app stops working.

Neither HTTPRequests or AMF Remoting works. It just gives Error 404 - Page not found.

It's not a router thing because sometimes it works. I believe it's a problem in AIR when active network adapter changes it keeps trying to go through 2G/3G. It's something Adobe should take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

The wifi could be blocking the 443 port - but I'd be surprised since https is a pretty commonly used protocol by standard users.  It if were blocked that could be your problem.  slmix's answer would detect that case - but since you aren't with the client it probably isn't practical to run that telnet (even if android supported it).

Comment: Just a side note that there's free app (connectbot) on Android that does full blown SSH. Quite impressive. The user that reported the problem tells me that he can access mobile site through his device browser that runs on the same phone as my app